# Date formatting a data frame string column

Tags: julia

Is there a way to do something like this (this is in R)

```
df$dataCol <- as.Date(df$dataCol, format="%Y%m%d")
```

where the dataCol is of the format "20151009".

1. Is there a way to change the column type to date in julia ?
2. I didnt find a way to do this with the Date.jl package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `Date` constructor with an argument for the format, 
but the syntax is slightly different.

```
using Dates
Date( "20141123", DateFormat("yyyymmdd") )
```

Comment: You might mention that in version 0.4 things have changed; *DateTime* is now part of Base.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the best way to do the first part of my question

```
using Dates
dateReported = map((x) -> string(x), df[:DateReported])
df[:DateOccurred] = map((x) -> if match(r"^((19|20)\d\d)(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])", x)!=nothing Date(x, DateFormat("yyyymmdd")) end, dateOccurred)
```